# HTTP Header Content-Length mod_deflate problems

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-headers, content-length, mod-deflate

Hi I have a HTTP Header in a file called download.php that forces a download.

The PHP Code:

```
$file = 'https://www.website.com/downloads/'.$download->stitle.'.zip';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

The download starts without a problem, but is always corrupt and the wrong size?

I am using gzip compression which I assume is causing the content-length to be incorrect for the download as the file is 603kb but the download window is saying 2.2kb.

.htaccess:

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain \
text/html \
text/xml \
text/css \
text/x-component \
application/atom+xml \
application/xml \
application/xhtml+xml \
application/rss+xml \
application/javascript \
application/x-javascript \
application/json \
application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
application/x-font-ttf \
application/x-font-woff \
application/font-woff2 \
application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
image/svg+xml \
image/x-icon


# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

I added the following to exclude zip files and the download script:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.zip$ no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI download\.php$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

But the downloaded file is still corrupt and the wrong size (7.7kb).
The download window now displays no file size.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I am getting the warning: filesize(): stat failed for https://www.website.com/downloads/free-font-family-poppins.zip

If I go to the location the file begins downloading with the correct size, so the file exists, I also changed the permissions of the file and folder to 777 to check it wasn't a permission problem, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download of .zip file runs a corrupted file php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088267/download-of-zip-file-runs-a-corrupted-file-php)

Comment: Tried the suggestions on that question but no luck.
Edited my question with the error I am recieving.

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302953/warning-filesize-stat-failed-for-img-jpg

Comment: That question was because his file location did not exist as his code was wrong.
Mine exists.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

filesize() function does not accept HTTP or HTTPS.

Changed the file location to the server filepath and is now functioning correctly.