# Why I can't filesize() to image in php

Tags: php

When I use `filesize()` to scan my folder's file ,
I can get every file name, but I only get .php .html file size .

This is my get folder file list function:

```
function showFileList($Member){

    $memberAccount = trim($Member->getAccount());
    $dir = "/home/s/x071/WWW/UserFile/${memberAccount}";  

    $array = scandir($dir);

    $fileList = scandir($dir);

    $size = 0;

    for($i=2;$i<count($fileList);$i++){
        $fileListWithOutRoot[$size] = $fileList[$i];
        $size++;
    }

    return $fileListWithOutRoot;
}
```

and this is get filesize:

```
function getFileSizeList($Member){

    $fileList = showFileList($Member);

    for($i=0;$i<count($fileList);$i++){

        $fileSizeList[$i] = filesize($fileList[$i]);
    }

    clearstatcache();

    return $fileSizeList;
}
```

When I get other file, I always get

> Warning: filesize(): stat failed for QQ123.jpg

I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Give more example of a file that can not be filesized.

Comment: Problem can be with large files. More than 2GB. But so big is not any image.

Comment: like .jpg .png .doc .txt ...

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Warning: filesize(): stat failed for img.jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302953/warning-filesize-stat-failed-for-img-jpg)

Comment: I don't upload , I just only read file's size

Comment: Start by checking whether the file is readable to your script ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer!!
I use absolute path that's work!!
filesize( 'Pass parameters here')

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that works.

```
$files = scandir('.');
foreach($files as $file) {
    if (is_file($file))
        echo $file.' '.filesize($file).'<br>';
}
```